# Cant get Moment .isBetween() to work properly

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to verify that dates from a Db is not overlapping with event dates from Full Calender. The inputs are all strings from the beginning. The moment().isBetween() always gives false no matter what. What am I doing wrong?

```
var format = 'YYYY-MM-DD h:mm',
            start = "2017-12-08 09:00",
            end = "2017-12-08 10:00",
            checkStart = "2017-12-08 09:00";

            var startDate = moment(start).format(format),
                endDate = moment(end).format(format);

            var startDatetoCheck = moment(checkStart).format(format),
                endDateToCheck = moment(checkStart).add(1, 'hours').format(format);

            var bool1 = moment(checkStart).isBetween(moment(start).format(format), moment(end).format(format));
            var bool2 = moment(endDateToCheck).isBetween(moment(start).format(format), moment(end).format(format));
```

Comment: Maybe it's because the variables `start`, `end` and `checkstart` are not declared with `var`?

Comment: thats justa miss here in the editor. Also fix it.

Comment: You need to do `isBetween(start, end, null, [])`, where the `[]` means "start and end inclusive": https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/

Comment: Why do you use `format` on every single moment object instead of just using the object itself?

Comment: Because I am new to the moment library. Please show me how it should be done if you have the time.

Comment: Cleaned up version: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/94qLj01g/

Comment: @AllramEst Just a heads up: I flagged this as "rtfm".

Comment: @AllramEst Replacing the bad code in your question with the fix is nonsense; the suggested method is to answer your own question (but obviously only if nobody has answered with a fix already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `moment(data0).isBetween(date1, date2)` use strict comparison.

> Version 2.13.0 introduces inclusivity. A [ indicates inclusion of a value. A ( indicates exclusion. If the inclusivity parameter is used, both indicators must be passed.

```js
var format = 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm',
    start = "2017-12-08 09:00",
    end = "2017-12-08 10:00",
    checkStart = "2017-12-08 09:00";

var startDate = moment(start).format(format),
    endDate = moment(end).format(format);

var startDatetoCheck = moment(checkStart).format(format),
    endDateToCheck = moment(checkStart).add(1, 'hours').format(format);

var bool1 = moment(checkStart).isBetween(moment(start).format(format), moment(end).format(format),  null, '[]');
var bool2 = moment(endDateToCheck).isBetween(moment(start).format(format), moment(end).format(format),  null, '[]')

console.log(bool1)
console.log(bool2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.19.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is the deprication warning anything to be concerned about?

Comment: to make the code as clean as possible, where do you think the format should only go?

Comment: @AllramEst It's because you used `h` in your format String. You don't need the format for the check though.

Comment: Edited. There is not warnings now

Comment: Works like a charm now. Ill update my question with the working code.